android unit test private listener called or not
I read this awesome post. the listener in that post is created by user then set to the object. so we can mock the listener then verify times to check if it's called or not.
But my case the listener is a private object created in the object, we have api to get the listener but no api to set the listener in.
What's proper way to unit test this private listener:
The code sample:

class EventMonitor {
    public interface IEventListener {
        void onFirst(int value);
        void onSecond(int value1,int value2);
    };
    private IEventListener mEventListener = new IEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFirst(int value) {
            //dofirst
        }

        @Override
        public void onSecond(int value1, int value2) {
            //doSecond
        }
    };

    public IEventListener getEventListener(IEventListener listener) {
        return mEventListener;
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        mEventListener.onFirst(0);
        mEventListener.onSecond(1,1);
    }
}

How to verify onFirst and onSecond has been called?

The simplest way is to make your private listener VisibleForTesting:
@VisibleForTesting
public IEventListener mEventListener = new IEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFirst(int value) {
        //dofirst
    }

    @Override
    public void onSecond(int value1, int value2) {
        //doSecond
    }
};

Then in your test just do the same, the mEventListener is public in unitTest code without warning:
class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Mock
    lateinit var listener: EventMonitor.IEventListener

    @InjectMocks
    private val monitor = EventMonitor()

    @Before
    fun initMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)
        monitor.mEventListener = listener
    }

    @Test
    fun addition_isCorrect() {
        monitor.doStuff()

        verify(listener, times(1)).onFirst(0)
    }
}

There will be a warning if you try to access mEventListener from the main code. But it still builds successfully, so it's not 100% private
